# Unique identifier as primary key when syncing databases

Tags: sql-server, database-design, synchronization

I have spent the best part of a day researching and testing different methods of syncing a SQL server database with CoreData on the Mac. I have tested both INT's and GUID's (sequential GUID's also) as my primary keys and although GUID's are by far the worst in terms of performance I can't see no other way of ensuring uniqueness across systems.

Is using GUID's for primary keys the wrong way to go when syncing data between platforms? I find it hard to believe that companies use GUID's when syncing, but most articles I read on the subject seem to point to just that. If developers are using GUID's does anybody know how performance can be improved? I tried using a GUID as a primary key with a non clustered index and created a date field as my clustered index with no great performance improvement.

Any help would be much appreciated, especially if you have tackled a similar problem.

Comment: Both answers are correct but decided to go with Marks solution as having a GUID as a PK with a non clustered index and a createdDate field with a clustered index. For anybody else looking at this question I ran a test with 50000 records similar to this one (http://www.fotia.co.uk/fotia/DY.19.NewSequentialId.aspx) with my configuration and got similar results to the NEWID test. I don't have huge amounts of data so the performance sacrafice over good synchronisation is worth it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUIDs make syncing a lot easier. Sequential guids will alleviate the fragmentation issue strongly, leaving only the 16 byte column size as the major issue.

As long as you ensure you have another sequential and narrow column as your clustered key, you'll save a lot of space for your nonclustered indexes - it seems like you already know this.

Assuming you're not dealing with GBs of data, performance shouldn't be that affected by a GUID in this case, given you've already handled the GUID column with proper care.

If you only need to sync two systems, I've previously created systems where A would use an identity(-1,-1) as the primary key where the other system used an identity(1,1) as the primary key. That ensure easy syncing while keeping the primary key nice and narrow. Won't work for more than two systems however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it does make a lot of scence. There will be other systems that will be coming into the sync mix, iPhone, iPad etc. However these will all use the SQL Server as their main data source, but doesn't mean the client won't want multiple device syncing in the future at some point :) I was going to go with sequential GUID's but performance will be lost as unique ids generated on the Apple devices (UDID's) will be synced back to the main data source ( SQL Server) thus disrupting indexes and page files.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, when you use GUIDs you may come across huge fragmentation of the indexes that use it as the key. Other ways of ensuring uniqueness across systems is to

use identity columns and seed them to different non-overlapping ranges:

```
1-100 million server A
100million1 -200 million server B
```

etc

or to use composite keys (identity int + location code) to distinguish original locations of data:
Three different rows:

```
1 AB
1 BZ
1 XV
```

Regards

Piotr

Comment: I did think about using composite keys identity int + device type ID, but though that may be a bit messy and may cause me issues down the line with my aspnet mvc routing as would have to create routes like /user/3?deviceid=2 or something of that nature.

Comment: +1 for the "original location of data" solution--which, alas, probably only works if you have control over said original locations.